# How to subtract data from row2 from column A and Row1 from column B?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having one table that contain 3 columns named as ID,logged_in,Logged_out.

| ID | logged_in | logged_out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24456 | 10:00:00 | 11:20:00 |
| 24456 | 11:30:00 | 13:00:00 |
| 24456 | 13:30:00 | 16:10:00 |
| 24456 | 16:20:00 | 19:00:00 |

I want to subtract Second row from logged_in with First row from logged_out and store the data into a new column and if there is nothing to subtract it need to populates as 00:00:00.

Ex : 2nd row from Logged_in is 11:30:00 and 1st row from logged_out is 11:20:00 so the output will be
11:30:00 - 11:20:00 =0:10:00

expected Output will be like this.

| ID | logged_in | logged_out | Total_duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24456 | 10:00:00 | 11:20:00 | 00:10:00 |
| 24456 | 11:30:00 | 13:00:00 | 00:30:00 |
| 24456 | 13:30:00 | 16:10:00 | 00:10:00 |
| 24456 | 16:20:00 | 19:00:00 | 00:00:00 |

Answer (score 0):

Using `TIME_DIFF()` with `LEAD()` we can try:

```sql
SELECT ID, logged_in, logged_out,
       COALESCE(TIME_DIFF(LEAD(logged_in) OVER (ORDER BY logged_in),
                          logged_out,
                          MINUTE), 0) AS Total_duration
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY logged_in;
```